# Reading xml from web

Tags: java, xml

I'm reading a xml from a specific url. But I'm getting this error

> [Fatal Error] :3:24: Open quote is expected for attribute "http-equiv"
>   associated with an  element type  "META".

The xml is missing encoding UTF-8, I added it but I'm still getting this error.
A help will be very appreciated.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class crawleycraw {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TransformerException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String urlString = "http://www.bnb.bg/";
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

        TransformerFactory factoryl = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer xform = factoryl.newTransformer();

        Transformer transformer = null;
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"no");

        xform.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post xml file also which you are using!

Comment: This is the example xml that the url generates:
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
  <GOLD>1</GOLD>
  <NAME_>Австралийски долар</NAME_>
  <CODE>AUD</CODE>
  <RATIO>1</RATIO>
  <REVERSERATE>0.794755</REVERSERATE>
  <RATE>1.25825</RATE>
  <CURR_DATE>23.05.2018</CURR_DATE>
  <F_STAR>0</F_STAR>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>`

Answer (score 1):

The URL `http://www.bnb.bg/`will return you HTML, not **XML**. Hence, when you parse it, it will be throwing en error, as its HTML, not XML.

Your code has other problem as well as answered by `Srinevu`

> Even if you download above URL using curl or wget or browser, save it
>   as example.xml, use any XML editor, you will see exact same error, you
>   are seeing by Java parser.

```
String urlString = "http://www.bnb.bg/";
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it. The url also generates xml, but I don't know how to read it. I'm trying different things but still not working.

Comment: @Teddy then you may have ask different question. Here is some [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/) to download the XML to file, once done you could apply your DOM manipulation/transformation logic.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine except, setting properties to null(transformer).. you may have problem with the response you are getting from URL. Here I have tried with simple xml string, it is working fine..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String urlString = "<Customers><Customer Name=\"Test_91\" Code=\"91\"/><Customer Name=\"Test_92\" Code=\"92\"/></Customers>";
        // URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(urlString.getBytes()));
        TransformerFactory factoryl = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer xform = factoryl.newTransformer();
        // Transformer transformer = null;
        xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        xform.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried it and I get this error
`[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.`